# Hive date format not supporting in impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

Hive date format not supporting in impala.

I created partition on date column in hive table but when i can access the same table  from hive_metadata in impala its showing

> CAUSED BY: TableLoadingException: Failed to load metadata for table
>   'employee_part' because of unsupported partition-column type 'DATE' in
>   partition column 'hiredate'.

Please let me know which date format does hive and impala commonly support.

I used date format in hive as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: I used date datatype in hive when i access the same table in impala its showing as invalid_type. Does impala doesnt support date datatype.
Query : describe employee;   Hiredate -- invalid_type

Answer (score 3):

Impala doesnt support the hive date format.
You have to use a timestamp (which means that you will always carry time but it will be 00:00:00.0000). Then depending on the tool you use after, you have to make a convertion again unfortunately.